# Using Javascript to replace an angular div with different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm currently working on a website project that involves using a couple of elements from a common package. The elements are a header and a footer, and I don't have the ability to change these elements because other websites are using them.

Now I need to change some of the elements, some text and anchors need to be changed. The only option I have is to replace them.

I currently have the following element:

```
<div class="visible-element">
<p style="display: inline-block;" class="ng-binding">Need a hand?</p>
<a href="tel:(+351) 217 907 610" class="ng-binding">(+123) 345 678 987</a>
<span>|</span>
<a href="mailto:yolo@mymail.com" class="ng-binding">yolo@mymail.com</a>
</div>
```

This element comes from the common package. What I need is to change the email and mailto fields. Since those don't have a specific class, one of the solutions I see is to replace the entire element.

```
// replace contents
var email = "mailto:yolo@mymail.com"
$(".visible-element").html(
    $("<a>").attr("href", "mailto:" + email).text(email)
);
```

With this I can replace the above element with one that only has the email, but I still need the text and phone number.

I'm not really seeing how can I concatenate the elements to form the original class but with all the elements needed.

Comment: Use `.empty()` and then `.append()` the jQuery elements, exactly as you have for the link, and add them 1 by 1.  You've pretty much got what you need already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select `<a>` elements with jQuery [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and change de value with [.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method. To change the text of the paragraph `<p>` you can select them and use again the `.text()` method.

Note if you have multiple places to change you could make a function to do this to avoid code duplication.

```js
(function ( $ ) {
  $( '.visible-element' )
    .find( 'p' )
    .text( 'My new other text here' );

  $( '[href="tel:(+351) 217 907 610"]' )
    .attr( 'href', 'tel:(+999) 999 999 999' )
    .text( '(+999) 999 999 999' );
    
  $( '[href="mailto:yolo@mymail.com"]' )
    .attr( 'href', 'mailto:me@myself.com' )
    .text( 'me@myself.com' );
} ( jQuery ));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="visible-element">
   <p style="display: inline-block;" class="ng-binding">Need a hand?</p>
   <a href="tel:(+351) 217 907 610" class="ng-binding">(+123) 345 678 987</a>
   <span>|</span>
   <a href="mailto:yolo@mymail.com" class="ng-binding">yolo@mymail.com</a>
</div>
```